How to correctly generate values to sign a SOAP envelope?
I'm working on signing a SOAP envelope using the xmlsec1 tool and the XML Digital Signature (XMLDSIG) standard. Here's the unsigned SOAP envelope I'm working with.
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference>
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue />
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue />
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data />
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <soapenv:Body>This is the body of the SOAP envelope</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

I generated the signed envelope using the following xmlsec1 command.
xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem private_key.pem --output signed_test.xml test.xml

The generated signed envelope is as below
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference>
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>mT/qq9iX2rvTrWOPfE8thFOKdbA=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>eZFngILLORe+r/07FupC9YPJEB3n3qhTyEi0+3J7Ivv/20rm7YNU5CllAiUmLUDJ
0A9/YLDo2BOokrNmAkpWtxU1xs83FH3NDecfqEj1hgIXsbkMhJLh2szssR6nRoff
ZV8FqWjQgUGS/IKLY0R9S/pxMxROKkiJ0J71hFHvuFphN/ZtpOGXdmX7oaS6EZmT
BeSu8R2jGiMVbGyf4+EBxkpSN6VF4tn3MWgfP+MV7ICw3MHHgNVd7Nqy7vS+kOtZ
hq2Tndg4b7O79XW2ni5tmpKJzHPDBfWFS+fEXHqkOFcPnb1rCk3oTOcaCqHOVZ1m
BbiB7r2bxyrKDL7uIA4suw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data/>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <soapenv:Body>This is the body of the SOAP envelope</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

I'm trying to understand how the  and  are calculated. Based on the SOAP envelope, here’s what I know:

The DigestValue uses the SHA-1 algorithm, as specified in the  element.
The SignatureValue is generated using the RSA-SHA1 algorithm, as specified in the  element.

When I hashed the <soap:Body> using sha1 algorithm, I get a different value. It would be highly appreciated if someone can show the detailed steps to correctly generate these values.

I checked the code of xmlsec in this github repo : https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec which I think is the correct one.
My knowledge of C and cryptography is very poor so I can't explain it to you directly.
But by searching for example "SignatureValue" in the whole project, I found this file https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec/blob/master/src/gcrypt/signatures.c#L805 at the line 805 where a comment explaining that SignatureValue is based on DSA-SHA1, here it is :
DSA-SHA1 signature transform

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-SignatureAlg:

The output of the DSA algorithm consists of a pair of integers
usually referred by the pair (r, s). The signature value consists of
the base64 encoding of the concatenation of two octet-streams that
respectively result from the octet-encoding of the values r and s in
that order. Integer to octet-stream conversion must be done according
to the I2OSP operation defined in the RFC 2437 [PKCS1] specification
with a l parameter equal to 20. For example, the SignatureValue element
for a DSA signature (r, s) with values specified in hexadecimal:


   r = 8BAC1AB6 6410435C B7181F95 B16AB97C 92B341C0
   s = 41E2345F 1F56DF24 58F426D1 55B4BA2D B6DCD8C8
 
  from the example in Appendix 5 of the DSS standard would be
 
  <SignatureValue>i6watmQQQ1y3GB+VsWq5fJKzQcBB4jRfH1bfJFj0JtFVtLotttzYyA==</SignatureValue>

Hope it can help you to find what you are looking for.
